# The maximal number of codewords in a code of length n with minimum distance at least d.

Tags: combinatorics, metric-spaces, coding-theory

A code $C$ of length $n$ is a subset of the set of all binary words of length $n$.  A codeword is an element in C.  The minimum distance of a code is the minimum Hamming distance over all pairs of distinct codewords.  Let $A(n,d)$ be the maximal number of codewords in a code of length $n$ such that the minimum distance of the code is at least $d$.

Here are some facts about $A(n,d)$ that I understand.  If $d>n, A(n,d) = 1.$  If $d = n$ then $A(n,d) = 2$ because we can choose a word and its complement to be in the code.  If $d = 1 $ then $A(n,d) = 2^n$ because every word could be in the code.  If $d = 2 $ then $A(n,d) = 2^{n-1}$ because we can choose the words with the same parity to be in the code.

The known values for $A(n,4)$ are given in [Sloane's OEIS A005864](https://oeis.org/A005864).  There is a link to a table of $A(n,d)$.  In the link it is stated that:  If $3*d/2 > n$ then $A(n,d) = 2$.  Is there an easy explanation for this?

Also the link states:  $A(n-1,2e-1) = A(n,2e)$.  I am trying to figure out why this is true as well.

I do not have any background in coding theory.  I know some basic combinatorical enumeration techniques that might apply to counting binary words.  I would like to see a gentle derivation of the above two statements.

Comment: And for the other part: add an extra bit to all the words so that they have an even weight.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate.  I do not agree that if 2*d/n = n then A(n,d) = 3.  In particular, A(3,2) = 4.  This is a case where d = 2 so A(n,d) = 2^(n-1).

Comment: @ Dilip Sarwate.  There was a typo in my post which I have now edited.  The cases I am interested in are when 3*d/2 >n then A(n,d) =2.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen  I do not understand what you mean.  Is the weight of a word equal to the number of 1's in the word?  What words am I supposed to "add an extra bit to".?

Comment: Juts check what Dilip Sarwate wrote. He answered the corrected version (because he knew what the correct version would be). And that extra bit? To the words of a code of length $n-1$ and distance $2e-1$.

Comment: Also note that there are no restrictions placed on the number of 1's in a code word.  We seek the maximal size of a code with minimum distance at least d without regard to any relationships that the words in the code may have.

Comment: Yes, I knew that. The process I described can be done to any code. Furthermore, it is a two-way street. You can also "puncture" that extra bit away to head in the opposite direction.

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen.  What Dillip Sarwate had posted was wrong and with all due respect I think that what you are suggesting is also wrong (or at least unclear).  I am going to add a bit  "to the words of a code of length n -1 and minimum distance at least 2e -1" to form a code of length n with minimum distance 2e?  For example A(5,3) =4=A(6,4).  A maximal code of length 5 with minimum distance 3 is { (00000), (11100), (00111),(11011) }.  How do I get a code of minimum distance 4 by adding a bit to these words?

Comment: @Geoffrey Critzer.  Even when you are frustrated because you can't figure out the answer to a simple problem you should not jump to conclusions and think that what you can't understand is wrong.  What is posted above by Jyrki Lahtonen is not only correct but is stated in the most clear and understandable manner possible.  Add a bit to the words of length n-1 to make them of even parity.  The code you have posted above corresponds to { (000000), (111001),(001111),(110110) }.